# Using a for loop to print index number and the character in that index in a string array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to use a for loop to examine every character in a single dimensional string array and print "Character [a] is uppercase" or "Character [b] is lowercase" or "Character [c] is a space." I also have to print the index number and the character in that index.

I thought I was supposed to create separate strings with uppercase letters and lowercase letters but turns out I was wrong. I also don't know if I'm supposed to convert the string array into a char array?

I think I'm supposed to use `charAt()` method but I don't know how.

This is what I had done:

```
for(x = 0; x < fullName.length(); x++)
{
    if(fullName[0] == nameUpperCase[2]);
    {
        System.out.print("character [0] located at position [0] is  lowercase");
    }

    if(fullName[1] == nameLowerCase[4]);
    {
        System.out.print("character [b] located at position [1] is uppercase"); 
    }
}
```

As you can see, I couldn't even figure out how to use the loop to print 'a' or 'b' and so I had to manually insert each one along with the position they're in...

Comment: Can you give us some sample input / output if possible?

Comment: is x declared somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're comparing two Strings (ie the arrays are `String[]`) then your code is comparing the memory reference of each string, which will be different.

In order to compare `String` for equality, you need to use the `equals` method.

```
for(x = 0; x < fullName.length(); x++)
{
    if(fullName[0].equals(nameUpperCase[2]));
    {
        System.out.print("character [0] located at position [0] is  lowercase");
    }

    if(fullName[1].equals(nameLowerCase[4]));
    {
        System.out.print("character [b] located at position [1] is uppercase"); 
    }

}
```

I would also recommend you take some of the ideas from the other answers.

Convert the original `String` to a char array instead...

```
char[] fullName = name.toCharArray();
```

Or you could simply get the char at the given index...

```
for(x = 0; x < originalString.length(); x++)
{
    char charAt = originalString.charAt(x);
    if(Character.isUpperCase(charAt));
    {
        System.out.print("character [0] located at position [0] is  lowercase");
    }

    if(Character.toUpperCase(originalString.charAt(1)) == originalString.charAt(4));
    {
        System.out.print("character [b] located at position [1] is uppercase"); 
    }

}
```

**Updated example**

Now that we've established that we can't compare `String` values with `==`, here's a working example of what I think you want achieve...

```
String value = "This is a simple string";
for (int index = 0; index < value.length(); index++) {

    String whatIs = "Unknown";
    if (Character.isUpperCase(value.charAt(index))) {
        whatIs = "Upper case";
    } else if (Character.isLowerCase(value.charAt(index))) {
        whatIs = "Lower case";
    } else if (Character.isSpaceChar(value.charAt(index))) {
        whatIs = "Space";
    } else if (Character.isDigit(value.charAt(index))) {
        whatIs = "Digit";
    }

    System.out.println("Character @ " + index + " (" + value.charAt(index) + ") is a " + whatIs + " character");

}
```

Which outputs

```
Character @ 0 (T) is a Upper case character
Character @ 1 (h) is a Lower case character
Character @ 2 (i) is a Lower case character
Character @ 3 (s) is a Lower case character
Character @ 4 ( ) is a Space character
Character @ 5 (i) is a Lower case character
Character @ 6 (s) is a Lower case character
Character @ 7 ( ) is a Space character
Character @ 8 (a) is a Lower case character
Character @ 9 ( ) is a Space character
Character @ 10 (s) is a Lower case character
Character @ 11 (i) is a Lower case character
Character @ 12 (m) is a Lower case character
Character @ 13 (p) is a Lower case character
Character @ 14 (l) is a Lower case character
Character @ 15 (e) is a Lower case character
Character @ 16 ( ) is a Space character
Character @ 17 (s) is a Lower case character
Character @ 18 (t) is a Lower case character
Character @ 19 (r) is a Lower case character
Character @ 20 (i) is a Lower case character
Character @ 21 (n) is a Lower case character
Character @ 22 (g) is a Lower case character
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fullName[0] == nameUpperCase[2]
```

the above expression is wrong. i assume fullName is a **String** from your for loop as you are using **full.length()** method. fullName is not an array, so doing fullName[0] is wrong. to get a character in a string, use String.charAt(index) method.as you are beginner, please have a look at [String Class API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for reference.

you could do something like this i suppose:

```
    String[] s= {"Ab "};
    for(String ss: s) {
         for(int i=0; i<ss.length(); i++) {
             if(Character.isUpperCase(ss.charAt(i))) {
                 System.out.println("character "+ss.charAt(i)+" located at position"+i+ " is  lowercase");
             }
             else if(Character.isLowerCase(ss.charAt(i))) {
                 System.out.println("character "+ss.charAt(i)+" located at position"+i+ " is  lowercase");
             }
             else if(else if(Character.isSpaceChar(ss.charAt(i)))) {
                 System.out.println("character "+ss.charAt(i)+" located at position"+i+ " is  lowercase");
             }
         }
```

Comment: You could use `Character.isSpaceChar` instead of `== ' '` but otherwise it's correct ;)

Comment: Now I'm going to have to give you a +1. Be nice to explain why `fullName[0] == nameUpperCase[2]` is the wrong approach ;)

Answer (score 1):

There may be an easier way, but this could work.

```
if (str.toUppercase().equals(str)) {
    // It's uppercase.
}

if (str.toLowerCase().equals(str)) {
    // It's lowercase.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a `String`, you can simply use `charAt` to select characters. It is not possibly to select individual characters using, for example, `fullName[0]`. This notation *would* possible if `fullName` was a character array.

```
String fullName = "Stack Overflow";
for (int x = 0; x < fullName.length(); x++)
{
   char testChar = fullName.charAt(x);
   if (Character.isLowerCase(testChar))
   {
     System.out.println("character [" + testChar + "] located at position [" + x + "] is lowercase");
   }
   else if (Character.isUpperCase(testChar))
   {
      System.out.println("character [" + testChar + "] located at position [" + x + "] is uppercase");
   }
   else if (Character.isSpaceChar(testChar)) {
     System.out.println("character [" + testChar + "] located at position [" + x + "] is a space");
  }
}
```

Comment: A brief explanation why (you'd want to use `String.charAt`) would make it better answer. +1 though

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try,

```
    for(x = 0; x < fullName.length(); x++)
    {
        if( fullName[x].equals(nameUpperCase[x]) );
        {
            System.out.print("character [" + fullName[x] + "] located at position [" + x +       "] is lowercase.");
        }

        if( fullName[x].equals(nameLowerCase[x]) );
        {
            System.out.print("character [" + fullName[x] + "] located at position [" + x + "] is  uppercase."); 
        }

    }
```

It should work fine if **fullName, nameUpperCase and nameLowerCase** are string arrays. Although, looking at the solutions others have posted I'd suggest you look at those for clearer and cleaner code.

Comment: While you answer is on the right track, the OP does mention they're using a *single dimensional string array*. I'd update the answer to reflect the use of a `char[]` array so there is no doubt. Could earn you a down vote other wise...

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like this:

```
String s = "Hello World";
for (int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if (c == ' ')
        System.out.println("character located at position [" + i + "] is a space");
    else if (Character.isUpperCase(c))
        System.out.println("character [" + c + "] located at position [" + i + "] is uppercase");
    else if (Character.isLowerCase(c))
        System.out.println("character [" + c + "] located at position [" + i + "] is lowercase");
    // else character is not recognized
}
```

Of course, I have only used a single `String` here, but in the case of a `String[]`, you could simply apply this process to every member.